# How do I get the Frankly Trippy achievement?

Tags: achievements, treasure-adventure-world

The [description on the wiki](http://treasureadventurewiki.com/Achievements) is just "Find an Easter Egg". How do I get this achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wear the shroom hat while sailing from Zwann to Boracay (at least that's how it popped up for me).

It might be tied to completion percentage, though.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it didn't work in my New Game+, but in my 100% save file it did